# deny certain links in scrapy linkextractor

Tags: python, scrapy

```
with open('/home/timmy/myamazon/bannedasins.txt') as f:
    banned_asins = f.read().split('\n')

class AmazonSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = 'amazon'
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com',]

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="a-last"]/a')),
            Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//h2/a[@class="a-link-normal a-text-normal"]',
            process_value= lambda i:f"https://www.amazon.com/dp/{re.search('dp/(.*)/',i).groups()[0]}"),
            callback="parse_item"),
            )
```

I have the following two rules to extract Amazon product Links which works correct,Now I want to remove some Asins from search `re.search('dp/(.*)/',i).groups()[0]` this retrieves the ASIN and places it in the format `https://www.amazon.com/dp/{ASIN}`, what I want to do is-- if asin in  `banned_asins` do not extract it.

After reading [Link Extractors Scrapy doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html),I believe its done by `deny_extensions` not sure how to use though

```
banned_asins= ['B07RTX74L7','B07D9JCH5X',......]
```

Comment: you can make a new list of links from the ASINs you have and then ban the new links

Comment: Rule(LinkExtractor(deny_extensions= banned_asins) ? That seems like the obvious answer, have you tried that? If so what was the result?

Comment: @pjmaracs as you can see I don't get the ASIN directly I have to use regex to find it which takes priorirty over deny_extensions

Comment: @programmerwiz32 thaks for the clarification. What in the doc do you see that process_value takes priority? Does it also take priority over deny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deny_extensions` won't work, it refers to common file extensions that are not followed if they occur in links, see [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/1f7413dc88d2eb0a1cc9c5a3286b6f01479cb77d/scrapy/linkextractors/__init__.py#L21) for the default values if it's not given.

You just filter out the banned asins in your [`process_value`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html) function. If it returns `None`, the given link is ignored:

> **process_value (callable)** –
>
> a function which receives each value extracted from the tag and
>   attributes scanned and can modify the value and return a new one, or
>   return `None` to ignore the link altogether. If not given, `process_value`
>   defaults to `lambda x: x`.

So it should be:

```
def process_value(i):
    asin = re.search('dp/(.*)', i).groups()[0]
    return f"https://www.amazon.com/dp/{asin}" if asin not in banned_asins else None
```

....

```
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//li[@class="a-last"]/a')),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//h2/a[@class="a-link-normal a-text-normal"]',
            process_value=process_value), callback="parse_item"),
        )
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'no longer works?' Do you get errors? Maybe the structure of the amazon.com site has changed and you'll have to adapt your `restrict_xpaths`. In order to understand what's going on you can place a `print(i)` in your `process_value` function.

Comment: no I believe "process_value" not longer works it must be lambda function

Comment: no, this is impossible: a named function is exactly equivalent to a lambda function, it makes absolutely no difference whether the functions is named or a lambda function. Did you test it with print(i) insides the process_value function to see if it is called and what arguments are passed to it?

Comment: yes, please try it, I was shocked when It just skipped it, even if you comment out the function it doesn't matter and call it in process_value (no error happens)

Comment: you can try it on scrapy shell of course that's where I am trying, and see the extracted_links

Comment: you're right: you must place the process_value function *before* the rules (outside your spider class) and remove the quotation marks, i.e. `process_value=process_value)`, I updated my anser